# Json Error in bundle products (MAGENTO)

Tags: json, magento, bundle

I've been working with Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 without any problem until using bundle products.
Every time I go to a bundle product, The page stops when the options product prices are listed.

Using Firebug says:

```
ReferenceError: bundle is not defined
bundle.reloadPrice();
```

Var bundle is not defined because bundle.phtml is not working properly although it´s been called by

getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?>

Following the issue I´ve seen that `$this->getJsonConfig()` works when is embeded into view.phtml: 
JsonConfig says:`{"productId":"3125","priceFormat":{"pattern":"...etc`, but it doesn't when bundle.phtml is loaded.

Here you can see the problem: http://www.mueblesbonitos.com/bundle1.html

I've searched on the forums and I've seen quite similar questions but I haven't reached a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.  The

> CJM Custom Stock Status extension

was causing a JSON conflict (even on a new Magento installation) so I decided to uninstall it and use another compatible extension.

I hope this helps someone and save a lot of time